# Add button to callback to export figure - dash Plotly

Tags: callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I know Plotly has a built-in function to export a figure. But the resolution is poor and there is limited control over additional parameters. Is it possible to include a button that links to a function? That way, it provides more parameters to the output figure, such as, size, resolution, file type etc.

I'm aiming to include a button within the figure (see below) that can be assigned to a callback function that exports a figure.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

url = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DS0321EN-SkillsNetwork/datasets/spacex_launch_dash.csv"

spacex_df = pd.read_csv(url)

spacex_df.rename(columns={'Launch Site':'Site'}, inplace=True)

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)


nav_bar =  html.Div([
     html.P("site-dropdown:"),
     dcc.Dropdown(
       id = 'Site', 
       value = 'Site', 
       options = [{'value': x, 'label': x} 
                for x in ['CCAFS LC-40', 'CCAFS SLC-40', 'KSC LC-39A', 'VAFB SLC-4E']],
       clearable = False
   ),
])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(nav_bar, className = "bg-secondary h-100"), width = 2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'pie-chart')),
            ]),
        ], width = 5),
    ])
], fluid = True)


@app.callback(
   Output("pie-chart", "figure"), 
   [Input("Site", "value")])

def generate_chart(value):
    pie_data = spacex_df[spacex_df['Site'] == value]
    success_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 0)
    failure_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 1)
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['success','failure'], values=[success_count, failure_count])])
    fig.update_layout(title=f"Site: {value}")

return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


# button to export figure
def export_figure(fig):

    fig.write_image('output.png', scale = 3)

    return fig
```

[image]

Comment: What did you mean by more parameters?

Comment: resolution, file type, size dimensions

Comment: I updated the solution to be more general with multiple figures and export buttons. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one callback which fills the interface up with the figure. The callback calls another function to exports the figure to your hard drive through clicking the button. In the function, you can change the parameters of exporting as you would:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

url = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DS0321EN-SkillsNetwork/datasets/spacex_launch_dash.csv"

spacex_df = pd.read_csv(url)

spacex_df.rename(columns={'Launch Site':'Site'}, inplace=True)

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)


nav_bar =  html.Div([
     html.P("site-dropdown:"),
     dcc.Dropdown(
       id = 'Site', 
       value = 'Site', 
       options = [{'value': x, 'label': x} 
                for x in ['CCAFS LC-40', 'CCAFS SLC-40', 'KSC LC-39A', 'VAFB SLC-4E']],
       clearable = False
   ),
])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(nav_bar, className = "bg-secondary h-100"), width = 2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'pie-chart')),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                html.Button('Export', id='export-val', n_clicks=0),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                html.Div(id='confirm')
            ])
        ], width = 8),
    ])

], fluid = True)


@app.callback(
   [Output("pie-chart", "figure"),
    Output("confirm", "children")],
   [Input("Site", "value"),
   Input("export-val", "n_clicks"),]
   )
def generate_chart(value, n_clicks):
    pie_data = spacex_df[spacex_df['Site'] == value]
    success_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 0)
    failure_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 1)
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['success','failure'], values=[success_count, failure_count])])
    fig.update_layout(title=f"Site: {value}")
    text = export_figure(fig, n_clicks)
    return fig,text


# button to export figure
def export_figure(fig, n_clicks):

    if n_clicks != 0:
        fig.write_image('output.png', scale = 6, width=500, height=600)
        return "Your figure has been successfully exported!"
    else:
        return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hamzah. Is there a way I can not use `global_fig`? In case I have multiple figures and export buttons.